# Understanding ASP Net Core generated URL tag helper. [FromRoute] or [FromQuery]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm having this issue where there's an inconsistency from ASP Net Core when generating URL from view.

I will describe my question with 2 cases. Notice in `View` there's tag helper `asp-route-....`. I try to change the variable name in `asp-route-....` and it turns out that it generates an inconsisten URL

**Case 1:**

View

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-p_id="@item.CustomerContactInfoId" >Edit</a>
```

Generated URL

```
localhost/CustomerContactInfo/Edit?p_id=1 // So in controller I have to use FromQuery instead of FromRoute
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromQuery(Name ="p_id")]int? p_id) 
//OR 
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? p_id)
```

Question = why the generated URL is not like this

```
localhost/CustomerContactInfo/1
```

---

**Case 2:**

View

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerContactInfoId" >Edit</a>
```

Generated URL

```
localhost/CustomerContactInfo/1  // So in controller I have to use FromRoute instead of From
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromRoute(Name ="id")]int? p_id)
//OR 
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
```

Question = why the generated URL is not like this

```
localhost/CustomerContactInfo/Edit?id=1
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out because the default name for route parameter is `id` as you can see in  `Startup.cs` `configure()` method here

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

**THEN**

If you change `{id?}` with `{p_id?}`, based on your question in `Case 1` it will be

```
/*-------In View--------------*/
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-p_id="@item.CustomerContactInfoId" >Edit</a> 

/*------Generated URL---------*/
localhost/CustomerContactInfo/1

/*------In controller---------*/
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromRoute(Name ="p_id")]int? p_id) 
//OR 
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? p_id)
```

And in `Case 2` will be

```
/*-------In View--------------*/
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerContactInfoId" >Edit</a> 

/*------Generated URL---------*/
localhost/CustomerContactInfo/Edit?id=1

/*------In controller---------*/
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromRoute(Name ="p_id")]int? p_id)
//OR 
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? p_id)
```

You can find the explnation in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1#asp-route-value)